# Generate form directly in template ? (Django)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a menu where I want to put forms.
This menu is part of my template `base.html` which will be extended by all my views.

My simple form (in `myapp/forms.py`)

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="name")
    password = forms.CharField(label="password", widgt=forms.PasswordInput)
```

The simplest way I see it would be to generate the form from `views.py` in a method that will be called in every method from my views.Something like :

```
def preprocess(request):
   forms = []
   forms.extend(LoginForm(), SubscribeForm(), ... )
   return forms

def myview1(request):
   forms = preprocess(request)
   ...
   return render(request, "template1.html", locals()) #template1 extends base.html

def myview2(request):
   forms = preprocess(request)
   ...
   return render(request, "template2.html", locals()) #template2 extends base.html
```

base.html :

```
<html>
{{ forms[0].as_p }}
{{csrf_token }}
</html>
```

All this code is untested and is really probably not working due to some mistakes, but I bet you get the idea.

Is it the best way to do it ? Some way to directly generate a form in the template ? I could also write the form by myself in the template but that's not what I want to achieve.

Comment: The magic word is [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/templates/#context-processors).

Comment: @knbk Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for !